# how to read .FIC .NDX file with Python

Tags: python, windev

I want to read a .fic file and extract data using python, this file is created by old version windev is any solution exist ?
I found these files in the database of windew

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one time job for data extraction you can easily convert it to excel format than read it with python.
Otherwise, using python you can call a windev exe that does the conversion job.

Comment: A long time ago, but trying anyway.
I need to access the tables too. I can connect with odbc (and thus pyodbc etc) to a database, but that doesn't support the file passwords it seems. Do you know how the windev solution here works?